# Automate Rename files from 1 to unlimited number

Tags: bash, terminal, automounting, cygwin

How to rename multiple files starting from 1 to unlimited ( to finish all files ) ?

My files looks like:

```
file.jpeg.jpg
fileA.jpeg.jpg
fileB.jpeg.jpg
```

Output:

```
1.jpeg.jpg
2.jpeg.jpg
3.jpeg.jpg
```

I'm using Cygwin so I can't install packages

Comment: You may want to expand on the _I'm using Cygwin so I can't install packages_. Cygwin is all about installing Unix _packages_ for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
n=0; for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "$((++n)).jpeg.jpg"; done
```

Or, the same thing spread out over multiple lines:

```
n=0
for f in *.jpg
do
    mv "$f" "$((++n)).jpeg.jpg"
done
```

#### How it works

- `n=0`

  This initializes the variable `n`n.
- `for f in *.jpg; do`

  This starts a loop over all files in the current directory whose names end with `.jpg`.
- `mv "$f" "$((++n)).jpeg.jpg"`

  This renames the files as you want.  In bash, `$((...))` does arithmetic.  Here, we have it increment `n` each time it is run.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

This code will work even if there are files whose names contain spaces, tabs, newlines, or other difficult characters.

#### The Order

The glob `test*.in` is expanded into a list of files in *alphabetical* order.  This is documented in `man bash`:

> bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these
>   characters appears, then the word  is  regarded  as  a  pattern,  and
>   **replaced with an alphabetically sorted list** of filenames matching the
>   pattern (see Pattern Matching below).  [Emphasis added.]

Note that the meaning of alphabetical sorting may depend on your locale setting.

Comment: it rename it all but the order of files was changed how can I fix that ?

Comment: This renames them in alphabetical order. (The shell expands wildcards alphabetically.)  What order did you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
j=0;
for i in `ls`
do
     mv $i $j.jpeg.jpg
     j=`echo $j + 1 | bc`
done
```

Comment: it rename it all but the order of files was changed how can I fix that ?

Comment: @SHW do not parse ls! see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of files can be "unlimited", there is a builtin limit to the size of the command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit . Therefore, I would use `find` to solve this. E.g, in bash:

```
cd /path/to/directory
n=1
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpeg.jpg" | sort |  while read file; do
    mv "$file" $n.jpeg.jpg
    let n=n+1
done
```

The steps are as follows, line-by-line:

1. Change to the appropriate directory
2. Set the file counter to 1
3. `find` in the `.` (current) directory, and do not burrow into any subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`), and look at only regular files `-type f`, and return only files whose name matches the pattern `*.jpeg.jpg`, and print their names (by default). Pipe the output of the find command to the sort command so they are in order (sort can handle very large stdin). Pipe the output of sort to a `while`/`read` loop, which will set each line of input to the variable `file`, line by line.
4. Move the file whose name is stored in the `file` variable to a file named by the `$n` variable, concantenated with the string `.jpeg.jpg'
5. Increment the variable n
6. Loop to the next filename.

You can handle a very large directory this way. It's fairly immune to 'weird' (aka "characters not in the printable ASCII set") file names. It can be made even more immune but that's probably unnecessary for this case, I'm guessing (It involves using the `-print0` option, and probably the `xargs` command).

Comment: Actually, I found that I fret too much. From me answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit/33619281#33619281 , we can see that a for loop as posted here above by @John1024 can handle a very large group of files. I don't know how large... my tests showed 500,000 files of 18 characters each are handled just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This version will keep the new files in the same order when you list them aphabetically (as in the output of `ls`):

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
for f in *.jpeg.jpg
do
     mv "$f" "$(printf '%011d.jpeg.jpg' $i)"
     i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```